# Laravel 5.1 modular blade template

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm using the modular structure as described in the blog below with Laravel 5.1
http://ziyahanalbeniz.blogspot.com.tr/2015/03/modular-structure-in-laravel-5.html

In fact I have a module user which has the following structure:

- Controllers
- Models
- Translations
- Views
  -> index.blade.php
  -> register.blade.php

In my Views directory I have a index.blade.php file and a register.blade.php file.
In my index.blade.php file I use:
@include('register') in order to include the register file within my index php file.
But I get a view not found exception when calling my index file.

I have some trouble which is the correct path I have to add within my @include.
@include('user.register') doesn't work neither. Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should include the path relative to `resources/view` (no matter where you calling from), replacing "/"s by "."s.

For example:

```
yourproject/resources/views/template.php
yourproject/resources/views/module1/main.php
yourproject/resources/views/module1/foo.php
yourproject/resources/views/module2/main.php
yourproject/resources/views/module2/bar.php
```

Should be included as:

```
@include('template');
@include('module1.main');
@include('module1.foo');
@include('module2.main');
@include('module2.bar');
```

Remember that when you use `@include`, it does a literal copy of the file, as if you copied and pasted it. `@include` DOES NOT extends the file, so you can't replace `@yield` or `@section` tags when you use it.

In other words, the calling file becomes a parent. If you want to build a child view, you should use `@extends` instead.

Cheers